# MySQL connector for android studio 4.0

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, xampp

I have android studio 4.0 version, I need to implement a database using xampp. but I don't know which version of the MySQL connector use in android studio 4.0. What would be the version of the MySQL connector that I should use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? A direct connection from your Android app via JDBC to your MySQL server over the internet? Did you try anything?

Comment: Exactly that. I didnt try aniything. I just need to know which version of MySQL connector  i need to use, to make it compatible with android 4.0

Comment: You mean Android Studio 4.0 not Android 4.0, right? Do you know that a direct connection to MySQL over the internet is considered as an anti-pattern? But besides that why don't you try the newest JDBC driver version and check if it works?

Comment: yes, sorry, is anddroid studio 4.0. Okay, thank you,I will prove the newest JDBC driver version. Why is cosidered as an anti pattern?

Comment: The recommended pattern is to hide the database behind a service. So you can only directly access the exposed API e.g. via HTTP. Exposing a raw database connection to the world is a security risk. If someone is able to find the database user credentials he could not only read all the database data but also destroy data or even get access to the underlying server. Only exposing a service is a lot more safe, but you still have to keep in mind other attack vectors like SQL injection. Another issue is the protocol. HTTP or HTTPS is supported everywhere and with HTTPS you get encryption for free.

Comment: Okay. I m going to find ways to hide my database behind the service. Thank you very much for the explanation.